# Android Gallery issue - gallery size is bigger than expected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I've got Activity with gallery widget alongside with other views. I want gallery to be as wide as my Activity is, and I want my image to match gallery size. I'm a little bit confused with [ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html), but that's what I've chosen:

Part of my curtom adapter for Gallery:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView=new ImageView(activity);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    //imageView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    String imageUrl="my_uri.com/sample.png";

    imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, activity, imageView);

    imageView.setTag(imageUrl);

return imageView;
}
```

Part of my Activity layout:

```
 <Gallery 
       android:id="@+id/gallery"
       android:layout_below="@+id/tvDetailedDescription"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="#CCCCCC"
     />
```

[image]

What I need is to get rid of that extra grey part of gallery on top and bottom(marked red). I wonder, why does it have such size? Maybe I do something funny with that scaling type stuff?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ScaleType.CENTER_CROP` instead - this will make the image fit the full height while maintaining it's aspect ratio - ie some of the image on the left and right will not be visible.

Alternatively you could use `ScaleType.FIT_XY` - this will not maintain the aspect ratio and will stretch the image so that all of the image fits inside the ImageView.

Comment: I need aspect ratio saved. CENTER.INSIDE seems to be good, but I still have that grey extra space on bottom and on top.

Comment: Try `CENTER_CROP` then - that maintains aspect ratio.

Comment: That makes image to be larger that view, CENTER_INSIDE is how I want it to look like, but I don't know why gallery widget itself becomes greater than imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the layout params of the image view (set the height to fill_parent as well) -

```
Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

android:layout_weight="1" for gridview or parent.
you must use "hierarchyviewer" tools for better undestand 
what layout need to have design priority, 
for undestand what layout don't fill own parent.

I hope that it help you.